# My partial view is not passing the values to the model correctly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a huge problem that I'm extremely confused on. 
I'll give you a little background first. 
I have two models, one that contains the other like

```
public class AccountViewModel
{   
    public ChargeViewModel chargeViewModel { get; set; }
    other public values
}
```

Now I have a view, that references the partial view like so.

```
@model MyModels.AccountViewModel

[[Block_Header]]
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Header"); }
[[/Block_Header]]

[[ValidationSummary]]
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)      
[[/ValidationSummary]]

[[Block_ReloadOptions]]
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="amount-bar">
            <legend>Select an amount</legend>
            @{
                List<int> PresetValues = Main.Denominations.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Trim())).ToList();    
            }       
            @if (PresetValues.Count > 0){
                int i = 1;
                foreach (int value in PresetValues) {                    
                    <input type="radio" name="amount" id="amount@(i)" value="@value" @(Model.chargeViewModel.ChargeAmount == value ?　"checked" : "")>
                    <label for="amount@(i)">$@value</label>
                    i++;
                } 
            }           
            <label for="select-amount">Select Amount</label>
            <select name="select-amount" id="select-amount" class="select-amount" data-role="select">
                <option value="">Other</option>
                   @if (Model.chargeViewModel.OtherValues.Count > 0){                      
                        foreach (int value in Model.chargeViewModel.OtherValues)
                        {
                            <option value="@value" @(Model.chargeViewModel.ChargeAmount == value ? "selected" : "") >$@value</option>                           
                        }
                    }                   
            </select>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.chargeViewModel.ChargeAmount, new { id="hiddenAmount", value="0" })
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Some more forms here that arent relevant and then my partial view at the bottom as follows

```
@Html.Partial("MobileModelView", Model.chargeViewModel)
```

Now my partial view looks something like

```
@model VirtualNext.Web.Models.ChargeViewModel
<div class="ui-block-a">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="field-margin validate expiry-select">
                <label for="select-expiry-month" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Month</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExpMonth, Model.ddlMonths, new { id = "select-expiry-month", @class= "validate"})
                <label for="select-expiry-year" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Year</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExpYear, Model.ddlYears, new { id = "select-expiry-year", @class= "validate validateExpiry validateYear" })
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

So now I'm having a problem passing in the values of m.ExpMonth and m.ExpYear to my model in the controller. I have checked my Request.Form value and the values are populated, but not to the post method in my controller.

My controller looks like

```
public ActionResult MyAction(AccountViewModel model, ChargeViewModel chargeViewModel)

{}
```

Now I have all the data that I pass in directly through my main view, but nothing from the partial view is populating the model like I want it to. Now this is part of my mobile site I'm working on, and I actually have something extremely similar on my desktop side, so I'm really confused as to why it wont work. Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a FormCollection parameter to your controller action like this: `public ActionResult MyAction(AccountViewModel model, ChargeViewModel chargeViewModel, FormCollection values)`, and put a breakpoint in the beginning of the action to see if the ChargeViewModel property values are being posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong binding. You dont need 2 models in controller. You can bind you submodel with main model like

partial view

```
@model VirtualNext.Web.Models.ChargeViewModel
@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "AccountViewModel"; //bind to main model
}
```

controller with 1 model

```
public ActionResult MyAction(AccountViewModel model)
```

Additionaly i recomend you to pass the Prefix by ViewData to make your view more flexible.

```
@model VirtualNext.Web.Models.ChargeViewModel
@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = ViewData["htmlprefix"];
}
```

With this option you can use this view in many controller actions. just pass the prefix and bind your submodel to any model you need.

Answer (score 1):

Put your partial view in the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder.

Then, replace Html.Partial line in your View with this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChargeViewModel, "MobileModelView")
```

And, replace your Action with this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(AccountViewModel model)
{
  // Some code...
}
```

Comment: I cant rename that partial view, thats the only issue I can see from this answer.

Comment: It's fine. See the updated answer. You may not have to put it in the EditorTemplates folder when you specify the name. I'm not sure. You can try that.

Comment: Going to test this now.. I swear if this works you're the best

Comment: Unfortunately I had no luck getting it to work since the partial view wasnt displaying correctly. :/

Comment: What do you mean? It wasn't displayed at all or what? Is your partal view inside the EditorTemplates folder?

Comment: Oh it displayed too many fields.. however I got it to work using a little fix with max's code. Thank you nonetheless